# What will be the first value when we difference for ARIMA model

Tags: matlab, arima

I want to difference a nonstationary time series to fit an ARIMA model with X(t)=X(t)-X(t-1) formula (using `diff` function in MATLAB) but I can not figure out what should I use for first value since the is no value before the first one? Should I use zero or the same value as X(1)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "missing", and you will need to drop it from the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at statistical software in general, the 0th value should be "missing value". You should remove the 0th value in the fitted value and in the original data when plotting or calculating the RMSE unless RMSE would be bigger than it should be.